# Sort string + date by most current date in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array:

```
my @array = ( "\"Passing\" on Wed 12 Jan 2015 09:19:14 AM PST", 
              "\"Passing\" on Wed 12 Jan 2015 09:19:25 AM PST", 
              "\"Test Activation\" on Tues 14 Jan 2015 12:05:14 PM PST", 
              "\"Run Phase\" on Tues 14 Jan 2015 12:06:14 PM PST",
              "\"Test Activation\" on Tues 13 Jan 2015 11:43:12 PM PST")
```

I want to remove the duplicate string line BUT keep the one that is most recent. So I want it to look like:

```
       my @array = ("\"Passing\" on Wed 12 Jan 2015 09:19:25 AM PST", 
                   "\"Test Activation\" on Tues 14 Jan 2015 12:05:14 PM PST", 
                   "\"Run Phase\" on Tues 14 Jan 2015 12:06:14 PM PST")
```

I can't think of an easy way to do this... I was thinking about using some regex to compare the strings ( /\".*\"/ ) and have it remove duplicates it finds, but I'm not sure how to deal with the date/time.

Any suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: Your same code is invalid syntax, it's missing quotes.

Comment: You don't need to parse the dates if the array is in chronological order.  Is it?

Comment: @stark: the second Test Activation record preceeds the first in temporal order; the list in the array is not in chronological order, it seems.

Comment: It is not in chronological order

Comment: You could have your life made easier for you if the timestamp was presented in ISO 8601 format: `2015-01-14 12:06:14 -08:00` (or in UTC: `2015-01-14 20:06:14Z`).  For a uniform time zone, both those sort into time order using regular lexicographic sorting.  If you have different time zones, you need to map to UTC, but the parsing of the ISO 8601 format is arguably easier even for that -- not least because the time zone offset is unambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several options to parse and compare the dates.  Simplest is to use the built in [Time::Piece](http://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).  Use [strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece#Date-Parsing) for parsing and compare with `$time->epoch`.

Unfortunately for you, [abbreviated time zone names are ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). PST can mean US Pacific Standard Time or Philippine Standard Time.  This may cause strptime's %Z format to choke, YMMV.  From my strptime man page...

> The %Z format specifier only accepts time zone abbreviations of the local time zone, or the value "GMT".  This limitation is because of ambiguity due to of the over loading of time zone abbreviations.  One such example is EST which is both Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Australia Summer Time.

You may need to pre-process the date formats and convert them to time zone offsets.  You can use [Time::Zone](http://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Zone) for this and its distinctly North American slant.

```
use Time::Zone;
use Time::Piece;

my $offset = sprintf "%+d", (tz_offset("PST") / 60 / 60);

my $time = Time::Piece->strptime(
    "Wed 12 Jan 2015 09:19:14 AM $offset",
    "%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %z"
);
print $time->datetime, "\n";
print $time->epoch, "\n";
```

But try %Z first and see if it works.

Extracting the dates is also left as an exercise.